# How to handle the hibernate transaction in a booking site

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate. Please help me to design the below scenario.

In a booking site, a user can book a flight ticket alone or both flight ticket and hotel. How do I design the transaction management in hibernate so that in the below cases will be full filled.

A user booked for both flight and hotel,

1: flight booking has been successful, but the hotel booking could not due to some system issue. In this case the flight booking db will be successfully committed but the hotel db should rollback.

2: both the bookings done successfully. both the table committed.

3: if the flight booking failed both the booking should fail. Both the tables should be committed.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "Help me to design..."? Do you want to know which Entities you need?

Comment: I think,he is asking about how to implement this scenario. In a real world scenario of a holiday reservation go beyond that. There are many thing to consider before you save the booking in database(Before use hibernate). There are several states in such a package booking reservation you have to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you would use spring and hibernate below is the high level design of your problem:-

1. Create 2 entities one which maps to Flight Booking table and the other to the Hotel Booking table.
2. Create 2 DAO's(spring @Repository) one which takes care of any changes to Flight Booking and the other to Hotel Booking tables.
3. Create a method called bookFlight in the Flight Booking DAO/Repository and handle any exceptions and wrap it in a custom FlightBookingException checked exception and rethrow it to the caller. In this method you can think of persisting the flight details using the above flight hibernate entity.
4. Create a method called bookHotel in the Hotel Booking DAO/Repository and handle any exceptions and wrap it in a custom HotelBookingException and rethrow it with a proper message. Again  in this method you can think of persisting the hotel details using the above hotel hibernate entity.
5. Create a service layer(Spring @Service) to which you autowire these 2 DAO's and create a method called bookflightandhotel method which is annotated with @Transactional and call these 2 DAO methods(first flight and then hotel) within this bookflightandhotel method.

Now by default spring doesnot rollback transaction when an checked exception is thrown which is why you need to use the rollback feature of the @Transactional annotation to mark only the FlightBookingException. (eg:- @Transactional(rollbackFor = FlightBookingException.class)). This is done to achieve both point 1 and point 3 in your above question.

Now in spring configuration file you need to configure a JTATransactionManager (refer to the docs [Spring Transaction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html))

Finally you can write a Spring Junit to test the feature. Do let us know if you have any further doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Check Two phase commit. You might want to develop something around those ideas.

A way could be that you go to flight booking system and lock the resource. Then you go to hotel booking system and try to book that. If the booking is successful then you go and book the flight. As you are holding the lock to the resources you should be able to do that. However there are corner cases which you will need to take care of.